# how to import in the pyc file

Tags: python, pyc

The question: i can import some self made module in PY file, but when i transfer into the PYC file, the import error came into my eyes.

What i have tried: i have already append the module path in the system path and add the **init** file, but it can't work actually.

Please give me some help or advice, if you have once met this question

the files are in the following stage

```
test/
    f1.py
    f3.py
    tt/
        f2.py
```

the f1 file:

```
def f1(x):
    return x
```

the f2 file:

```
def f2(y):
    return y
```

the f3 file:

```
 import sys
    #sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\Kwoks\\Desktop\\test\\tt')
    #sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\Kwoks\\Desktop\\test')
    sys.path.append('../')

    from f1 import *
    from tt.f2 import *

    def f3(x,y):
        return f1(x)+f2(y)

    if  __name__ =='__main__':
        x = 3
        y = 3
        res = f3(x,y)
        print(res)
        print(sys.path[-1])
```

it is similar structure with my working project, i am so sorry that i can't put out my working code for the sake of my company, and i sincerely sorry for make any of you confused.

Comment: when i transfer it into the pyc and delete the py files,  import error no module named f1 .

Comment: Oh gosh, don't be doing that. `.pyc` files are not a thing you should be worrying about, you need to keep your `.py` files. Why did you think you should delete them?

Comment: maybe it is ridiculous, but when i finish my project, i was asked to keep the   code from being viewed, out of the need of work.

Comment: It's generally not so simple to do this with Python. You should look into "python code obfuscation" for some tips that will probably be better than a plain `.pyc` file and will work, but most efforts could be reversed if people really want to

Comment: Actually, thanks for your advice, maybe i will be confused with this mess for a few days. At first, i was drived by work to find the solution. But now, i was curiously about the .pyc file. One of my friend maybe once did something like that. But he was on the flight, so it is not possible for me to turn to him for help

Comment: @zhaguo don't hide important details like error messages in comments. [Edit] the question and explain what you saw so we can all share it.

Comment: i just edited the  question, sry for make you confused

Comment: Even if you _can't put out my working code for the sake of my company_ as you say, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which contains the essential parts needed to explain your problem to the community.

Comment: i have already put out the similar structure, problems didn't occur on whether i can run my code, but in the case when i ran the .pyc file,  i met the import error, while i can import successfully in the .py files

Answer (score 0):

I think i have got your points.

maybe when you transfer the .py files into the .pyc files, the file name contain the  version of the python. For example, you transfer the f1.py to the .pyc file, the file name will change into f1.cpython-3-5.pyc or something like that, so you just need to rename the pyc file, it will be ok.

PS: the name of the main file that you need to run in cmd, should keep the version of the python, that is to say, you need to keep the cpython-3-5 or something like that. If you rename it , you will get the error like "bad magic number"